# Why does Envoyer need to restart PHP FPM when deploying?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Envoyer and can any one explain me why do we need to restart PHP FPM when deploying.

Comment: What makes you think you need to restart it?

Comment: Can You explain a bit more?

Comment: Why do people downvote this question? It lead me to an answer for something I had been struggling with for hours.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because your new deployment is created in a different directory to the one currently being served by php. The release is symlinked from the directory specified in the nginx config.

In order for php to load the new deployment it must be restarted so it follows the updated symlink in your project folder.

Comment: what if we restart the nginx server instead of php-fpm?

Comment: For anyone else hitting this problem, envoyer does actually auto restart PHP FPM, but if the PHP version has changed on your server since first setting up envoyer it may be restarting the wrong process - see @0s1r1s comment below

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to update your nginx configuration to add/change these lines. It's my understanding that neither php-fpm nor opcache knows any file paths other than the paths that were set when the web server started running. By default, they are set to use `$document_root`.

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
```

Having `$document_root` set is fine for apps that do not get redeployed. The original symlink is captured by php-fpm and/or opcache. Since that path doesn't change, the deployment does not trigger any cache busting.

However, using the `$realpath_root`, the path to the files change after a deployment and are reexamined upon HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same problem like me. I just forgot to change the php version in the projects server setting in envoyer. So it was restarting the wrong php-fpm process.

Answer (score 0):

### Apache 2.4+

If you are using Apache, reset the opcache instead of reloading php-fpm:

```bash
/usr/bin/cachetool opcache:reset --fcgi=/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
```

You need to install `cachetool` for this:
https://github.com/gordalina/cachetool

This solution doesn't require sudo and it doesn't cause downtimes.

### Nginx

If you are using Nginx, just do the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` trick from Jeff Harris' answer.