# Why can't Envoyer restart my PHP after deployment?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, centos, envoyer.io

I am using Envoyer to setup deployments for my Laravel 5 project on a CentOS server.

I have installed php 7.3 on the server.

To restart php-fpm manually, I use the command `systemctl restart php-fpm`

However, for Envoyer to restart php, it is using `/bin/systemctl reload php7.3-fpm.service`.

How can I make Envoyer work with `systemctl restart php-fpm` or rename my php to be restarted with `/bin/systemctl reload php7.3-fpm.service` ?

[image: Following is the screenshot from the envoyer deployment summary]

Comment: may I know the reason behind restarting the php service?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318795/why-does-envoyer-need-to-restart-php-fpm-when-deploying